# can't locate VB picture

Tags: vb.net, path, image, locate

I've been modifying a picture, and the Old picture still does work even though I've delete all pictures in the vb project. Is there somewhere that still has reference to pictures in the project? If anyone could help me ,thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add more information in your question.

Comment: In project,I don't know it how to loadpictures.Because I can't found "LoadPicture" method in project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Solution Explorer, click the down arrow next to Form1.vb
Then double click on Form1.resx
This should bring you to any images in your project that you can easily save to disk by 
right clicking and selecting Export to File. 
Images are in the .resx file.

Comment: thanks a lot.my solution is GO to right side,find property of picture and locate picture you want to display.